# How to inlude multiple doxyfiles in a master doxyfile?

Tags: doxygen

I am working on a project which has multiple modules with their own doxyfiles. My idea is to have a single master doxyfile which can include other private doxyfiles to create a one big documentation of the project. The directory structure looks like following:

```
MyProject+
     |-Private_Prj1+
     |    |-Doc+
     |         |-doxyfile_privateprj1
     |-Private_Prj2+
          |-Doc+    
               |-doxyfile_privateprj2
     |-Doc+
           |-doxyfile_myproject(AKA Master Doxyfile)
```

How can I configure the `doxyfile_myproject` to include `doxyfile_privateprj1` and `doxyfile_privateprj2` in such a way that when I run Doxygen on the `doxyfile_myproject`, it then sequentially runs other doxyfiles?

Comment: Doxygen has the `@INCLUDE` to merge doxygen configuration files, but this will merge the different items and this is not what you want to accomplish (at least what I understand from the question). Doxygen is not a build system, so one cannot run doxyfile_myproject and then run doxyfile_privateprj1 and doxyfile_privateprj2, this is something one has to do with a script. When you want to run doxyfile_privateprj1 and doxyfile_privateprj2 with some specific settings  for that project and have some general setting for all projects than you can use `@INCLUDE` for this purpose`.

Comment: To couple projects, i.e. create cross references I advise to have a look at the chapter Linking to external documentation (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html) and the used tags here.